# Intellij Azure DevOps plugin getting SSL error on TFVC get

Tags: intellij-idea, azure-devops, ssl-certificate, tfvc

We are using Intellij IDEA 2020.1 Community Edition for Windows for development using the Azure DevOps plugin. We recently upgraded from 2019.2.2. We originally had problems with server certificates for the TFS server. We could contact the server by allowing Intellij to automatically accept unknown certificates. However, we couldn't pull a TFVC repo. Here is the stack trace for the error

[image]

We solved that on the old version by dropping the cacerts file we were given by the company into the .IdeaC2019.2\system\tasks directory. That didn't work on this version. We are able to browse the TFVC collection, but we can't create a workspace. We are able to get to the TFS repository from Chrome.

Thank you in advance for any help.

EDIT: The problem seems to be in the Microsoft tf command line utility. We are in virtual desktops that are very tightly locked down (extremely risk-sensitive business), so we can't put the cert in the default java keystore. The old tf utility had a profile command that would allow you to set properties. It doesn't exist now.

Comment: @Kevin. See my answer below. We had already exported the certificates, it was just a matter of redirecting the tf script. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem by creating a separate trust store and importing the certificates. Then we edited the tf script that the plugin uses. We added the TF_ADDITIONAL_JAVA_ARGS environment variable as below (Your paths will be different):

```
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=
set JAVA_OPITIONS=
set TF_ADDITIONAL_JAVA_ARGS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdealIC2020.1\tasks\cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

Comment: I can't. I work on a virtual desktop with no access to stack exchange.

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, this issue is indeed related with the certificates.

You could try the following steps to import the certificate.

1. Connect to Azure Devops Sever and export the certificate.

[image]

2. Navigate to the keytool path. I install the  Intellij IDEA 2020.1.4. So the path is `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\jbr\bin`
3. Run the script to import the certificates.

For example:

`keytool -keystore "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\jbr\lib\security\cacerts" -importcert -alias TFS -file "C:\test\tfs.cer"`

For more detailed information, you could refer to [this Blog](http://blog.majcica.com/2017/01/02/working-with-tfs-in-intellij-idea-via-vsts-plugin/).

On the other hand, you could also directly copy the required certificate to `security folder path`. `Intellij IDEA 2020.1.4 -> C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\jbr\lib\security`

Answer (score 1):

You can set custom JVM options in IntelliJ Idea from `Help` -> `Edit Custom VM Options...` and add the following in the file then restart IntelliJ Idea.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path to the cacerts file>
```

This should make IDE to use the cacerts file for trusted certificates.

Comment: We tried that. The problem seems to be with the Microsoft command line tool. Thank you for the answer, though.

Comment: If this is a cacerts issue on the cli then you can set the JVM arg globally by setting the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variabl